# Does Apache Http Client Handle Status Codes without messages? (Curl works but Http Client Fails)

Tags: java, http, curl, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

I have a servlet which uses Apache Http Client to make requests to a third party.  This has worked for years, but I am adding a new third party that I call via the existing servlet.  It is failing (404) from the servlet but works fine using command line `curl` from the same machine.

The really weird thing is it works against this third party's sandbox system, both from curl and from the servlet.  The only difference I see in the curl output between the two cases is how the *100 Continue* is returned from the third party server.  When I call the sandbox server (which also works from Http Client) the headers returned look like:

```
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
< HTTP/1.1 200
```

When I call the test/QA system (which works from curl but not from Http Client) the equivalent lines are

```
< HTTP/1.1 100
< HTTP/1.1 200
```

As you can see, the one which works returns `100 Continue` while the one which doesn't work just returns `100`.  As I understand it, including the message as part of the status is recommended but optional, so this is standard compliant.  And I am not getting an exception, I am getting a 404 page with an HTML body which does clearly come from this third party.

I have tried activating the "wire" logging (as per [their documentation](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/logging.html) - we are using log4j so added it to the existing properties file) but don't get any extra logging at all.  This is why am I using curl to try and see a difference in how the third party reacts.

I tried disabling the whole 100-continue (`.setExpectContinueEnabled(false)` when building my `RequestConfig`) but it didn't help (curl also works without the 100-continue)

Does the Apache Http Client fail in some weird way if the `100` doesn't include the message?  Or am I focussing on totally the wrong place?

(We are using 4.5.x branch of Apache Http Client still - I upgraded to latest 4.5.13.  I can try the 5.x.x series but that would impact a lot more I guess)

Comment: It does. Your problem is unlikely to be related to the status message having no reason phrase

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the client does handle the `100` without a message fine.

The issue was a third part that worked for `https://api.example.com/foo` but gave 404 for `https://api.example.com:443/foo`!  Don't ask...

The `curl` command included the port but curl must have stripped it out as it was the standard one.  Changed my servlet to do that and it worked.